# Macro to save file in a specific location

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have following macro which saves each sheet as .txt with file name as the name of the sheet in a workbook I want to modify this macro so that it saves each sheet as sheetname.txt in a specific location instead of save dialogue box popping up to choose file location each time.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Updateby20150910
    Dim xRet As Long
    Dim xFileName As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    xFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(ActiveSheet.Name, "TXT File (*.txt), *.txt", , "VBA for Excel")
    If xFileName = False Then Exit Sub
    If Dir(xFileName) <> "" Then
        xRet = MsgBox("File '" & xFileName & "' exists.  Overwrite?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "VBA for Excel")
        If xRet <> vbYes Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Kill xFileName
        End If
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFileName, xlUnicodeText
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If`enter code here
My_Exit:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "error"
End Sub`enter code here
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim path As String

    path = "yourpath\"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

         ws.Select
         If Dir(path & ws.Name) = "" Then
             ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & ws.Name, FileFormat:=-4158 'fileformat : txt
         Else
             Debug.Print ("File already exists!")
         End If

     Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Chris ..but the files are getting created empty